# How to output components by some of their fields?

Tags: reactjs

There is a code, but I don't understand how to implement the logic. I need the element to be displayed when its curObject.cathegory field matches the argument passed to the function

```
ShowElementsByName = (cathegory) => {
        this.setState(
            this.currentnews = this.state.gettednews.map (
                (curObject) => {

                    if (curObject.cathegory === cathegory) {
                        return (
                            <BlogComponent
                                name = {curObject.name}
                                content = {curObject.content}
                                cathegory = {curObject.cathegory}
                            />
                        )
                    }
                    else {
                        return (
                            null
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
        )
    }
```

Comment: You need to give us some more data and explain a bit better what you're trying to achieve. From the first glance at the code, the way you're trying to `setState` with a binding to `this.currentnews` seems a bit odd...

Comment: I believe you are using Objects if so use Object.keys() method first to get the array of the keys and then use map to map over the array and check it. Since you can't directly use map over the object, it should be used with a array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter blogs/news in your category. Then map it to components (this can by used in render function) and... i don't get what you what to keep in state.

```js
ShowElementsByName = (cathegory) => {
  const blogsInCategory = this.state.gattednews.filter(news => news.cathegory === cathergory);
  const blogsComponents = blogsInCategory.map(blog => (
          <BlogComponent
                name = {blog.name}
                content = {blog.content}
                cathegory = {blog.cathegory}
            />
  ))
  this.setState(blogsComponents)
  //or
  this.setState(blogsInCategory)
  // or what you need to keeep in this state
}
```